# Cache object only if it is Serializable

Tags: java, spring, caching, memcached, simple-spring-memcached

I have enabled Caching by using `@Cacheable` annotation on a method which has the following declaration:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "#t+ '_' + #key", condition = "#key != null")
public <T> T get(String t, VendorProperty<T> key, T defaultValue) {
    return get(t, key).orElse(default_value);
}
```

However, this throws `NotSerializableException` if the object it is trying to cache is not Serializable (for example: `DateTimeFormatter`).

I was wondering if it is possible to cache objects only when the object is Serializable to avoid this exception.

I am using `memcache` to cache the objects using `simple-spring-memcache` library.

PS: I can't implement the `Serializable` interface as `DateTimeFormatter` is a predefined class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion above won't work. #root.target is the target object being executed (in this case the service object). So it will appear to work because the service object is not serializable and so the object in question won't be cached but neither will anything else.

You need to leverage the "unless" condition using the result variable:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", 
           key = "#t+ '_' + #key", 
           condition = "#key != null"
           unless="!(#result instanceof T(java.io.Serializable))")
```